How to Perform Index Build on a Large MongoDB Collection Without Downtime in a Replica Set on Kubernetes?
I have a MongoDB replica set deployed using Kubernetes StatefulSet with three pods (mongo-0, mongo-1, and mongo-2). The setup includes one primary and two secondary nodes. I need to build an index on a large collection, but I want to avoid downtime during the index build.
My current approach:

Modify the StatefulSet to temporarily disable the logical session cache refresh by setting disableLogicalSessionCacheRefresh: true and port from 27017 to 27127.

Delete one secondary pod (e.g., mongo-1) so Kubernetes recreates it with the new configuration.

Run the index build on the newly created pod once it rejoins the replica set.

Revert the configuration for the modified pod and delete it again to rejoin the replica set with the original configuration.

Repeat the process for the second secondary node and finally the
primary node.


Is this the correct approach to avoid downtime while building an index on a large collection in a MongoDB replica set managed by Kubernetes?

Have you looked at https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/tutorial/build-indexes-on-replica-sets/#rolling-index-builds-on-replica-sets

And/or https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/core/index-creation/#comparison-to-foreground-and-background-builds
